# Command line tools that can convert Java nested/anonymous classes into top level classes

Tags: java, command-line, refactoring

I want to convert Java nested/anonymous classes into top level classes. I noticed that Eclipse Refactoring can help me to achieve this goal. I wonder is there any command line tool that can help me refactor Java source code.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. You could try https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ instead.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you want to do it from command line?
I suppose your want to apply the refactoring in batch mode?

I wonder if you could use Eclipse EASE to automate this task within the IDE? https://projects.eclipse.org/projects/technology.ease